# $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{2x})$ using little o function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, functions, asymptotics

Problem has to be solved specifically using little o function. I was going to transform $\sqrt{x+1}$ into $1+\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)$ and $\sqrt{2x}$ into $1+\frac{1}{2}t+o(t)=1+\frac{1}{2}(2x-1)+o(2x)$ but I don't know what to do with $\sqrt{x-1}$. Then, I tried:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{2x})=\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)-1-\frac{1}{2}(2x-1)+o(2x) +\sqrt{x-1})=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{1}{2}x+o(x)-\frac{1}{2}(2x-1)+o(2x) +\sqrt{x-1})$$

What should I do next (if this is correct)? What to do with two different o-functions ($o(x)$ and $o(2x)$) and with $\sqrt{x-1}?$

Comment: Should be obvious that the expression is asymptotic to $(1+1-\sqrt2)\sqrt x$.

Comment: The limit is $\infty$. Are you sure about $\sqrt{2x}$? Because $2\sqrt x$ makes for a more interesting problem.

Comment: @TonyK   yes I am sure it is $\sqrt{2x}$. Also I am aware that limit is inf but I would like to know the solution to this problem because I am practicing o-function for more difficult problems and I am struggling with basics

Comment: $o(2x)$ and $o(x)$ mean exactly the same thing (because if $f(x)/x\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, then $f(x)/2x\to 0$ too).

Answer (score 1):

Your expansion $\sqrt{x+1}=1+\frac12x+o(x)$ is only valid for *small* $x$, where $o(x)$ is understood as applying when $x\to 0$. When $x\to\infty$, you need $$\sqrt{x+1}=\sqrt x\left(1+\frac1x\right)^\frac12=\sqrt x\left(1 + \frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)=\sqrt x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}+o(x^{-3/2})$$

It is true that $o(x)$ is ambiguous in this regard: you must rely on context to deduce whether it applies as $x\to 0$ or as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Understood. Wouldn't then correct expansion of $\sqrt{x-1}$ be $x-1 = t$ and we could expand $\sqrt{1+(\frac{1}{t}-1)}$? @TonyK

Comment: @Nigruteen: Your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: How could we expand $\sqrt{x-1}$ ? @TonyK

Comment: @Nigruteen: That is easy, if you just follow my example. Think about it for a while.